# Downloading Google CLient Library in Mac Using Terminal?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-drive-api

```
    **//Ya I got it..**
```

The following steps i follow to get Google APi Objective CLient Library

Step1- Install Command Line Tools for Xcode and we can get it from **Xcode / Behaviors / Edit behaviors... / Downloads / Command Line Tools / Install**

Step2- In Terminal type... svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only

Comment: ya. thanks for information.. i have edited and corrected my fault.. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on magnifying glass on top-right of Mac (or command-space for shortcut). Type "terminal". Change your directory to where you want to download the app using command [cd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_%28command%29). Type this command `svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only`